# DHCP behind catalyst 3750 POE-48

Tags: cisco, dhcp, switching, cisco-catalyst

I'm a database developer that inherited and managing an environment, we recently got disconnected from our parent company.

Anyway we got couple of ESX servers, physical servers and we're having issues with the DHCP, no IP leases has been going on, we were attached to their DHCP, if I connect any PCs directly we get a lease, but not behind or over our switch.

what should I look for?  Anyone can help please?  I added Ip-Helper on the Vlan 90 but still no luck, doing a wireshark can only show dhcp discover messages, nothing else!

thanks
Jason

Comment: You need to provide more information. A good description of the network (a diagram would be great), the network devices, model, and configurations, etc. We can only speculate or guess (off-topic here) unless you give us the information.

Comment: Are your DHCP server and hosts located at the same subnet? If so, you don't need IP helper. Make sure DHCP server is reachable (simply ping) and check security features. DHCP snooping for instance.

Comment: Hi thanks for jumping in...appreciate the help guys, well main DHCP on ESX on a different subnet 10.35.2.x, clients are on 10.35.9.X, I've created another physical DHCP server on 10.35.9.X  but same issue when plugged to the main switch, but it 'd lease IPs if plugged in a desktop switch with couple of clients.   yes I can ping any DHCP from 10.35.2.x and 10.35.9.x with no issues.

Comment: Then your concerns are DHCP relay (IP helper) and L2 security features. There will probably be more to say if you provide configuration from device(s).

Comment: "sh run"  from the switch?

Comment: Please add the configuration to this question by editing your post. You can use {{ and }} for preformatted text.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to make the DHCP interface to hosts as a trusted interface.

interface 1/0/23
ip dhcp snooping trust